# How to execute a system command from an android application

Tags: android, linux

I would like to know how to execute a system command from an android application?

For example :

I would like to create a directory while I am running an application, so i need to execute the command "mkdir -p /x/y".

Please guide me with valuable pointers.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TO create a directory(for example on sd-card) you should use the other way:

```
File  file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorage() + "/folder-name");
file.mkdirs();
```

To write to external storage you should have the following permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To execute a system command usually used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l");`

Comment: Thats okk.. But how about any other System commands.. I used mkdir just for an example.

Comment: can you please post what's the problem? Do you write to sd card? If so, do you have a permission for this?

Comment: @Sen: There is a corresponding pure Java solution for almost all System commands. Unless you really want to allow user to run arbitrary command, there is usually little need to execute a system command through the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Sen,

I believe you are trying to run shell commands from an android app similar to an aandroid terminal app.Right?
This [link](http://saurabh-nigam.blogspot.com/2010/10/running-android-native-code.html) might be helpful.

Note:The post contains certain ways to drop a shell command from an app(do check those links in the post)

Answer (score 1):

I think Vladimir Ivanov means:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder-name");
```